# Identifying what reference of time is stored in my database

Tags: php, mysql, time

I am working on a system that is a relatively simple ticket submission feature. Tickets get a timestamp for when they were "created" and when they were last updated. The previous author simply used the following method:

```
$now = time();
//stripped array values from the database funciton:
"created" => $now,
"updated" => $now
```

That's when it's submitted, and then when updated it only uses the same function but just for "updated." I'm trying to setup a cron job script that deletes tickets on a user set time-frame based off of their last updated timestamp. My problem, however, is in my MySQL database, both "created" and "updated" are stored with a number like this:

```
1559936509
```

I'm having trouble finding out what this default storage method or time reference is. Is it nanoseconds? Is it a string being automatically created in mysql? If this is an actual time variable, how do I determine what kind? Online converters aren't shedding too much light.

Comment: The time is stored as an integer: the number of seconds since UNIX Epoch. Try [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to convert it back to human timestamp.

Comment: According to the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) - "Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)".